# Elasticsearch delete_by_query request getting terminated abruptly?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ES v7.3 and I am running a 5 node cluster, now I wanted to delete docs from my cluster based on some date range query and millions of docs have to deleted as per the condition so I am looking for an effective way to do this, currently I am using the below mentioned query on kibana,

```
POST test/_delete_by_query?scroll_size=10000&conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "co_receivedAt": {
              "lte": "2020-07-18T18:30:00Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this query seems to be very slow in deleting the docs and sometimes it gets terminated abruptly, I was monitoring this deletion task and got this response,

```
{
  "nodes" : {
    "ijZYh9CITH6ETFB-IfAEAg" : {
      "name" : "ip-1-0-4-113",
      "transport_address" : "1.0.4.113:9300",
      "host" : "1.0.4.113",
      "ip" : "1.0.4.113:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "ingest",
        "master",
        "data"
      ],
      "attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "33245122560",
        "rack" : "rack-01",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20"
      },
      "tasks" : {
        "ijZYh9CITH6ETFB-IfAEAg:288887138" : {
          "node" : "ijZYh9CITH6ETFB-IfAEAg",
          "id" : 288887138,
          "type" : "transport",
          "action" : "indices:data/write/delete/byquery",
          "status" : {
            "total" : 10017699,
            "updated" : 0,
            "created" : 0,
            "deleted" : 0,
            "batches" : 1,
            "version_conflicts" : 0,
            "noops" : 0,
            "retries" : {
              "bulk" : 11,
              "search" : 0
            },
            "throttled_millis" : 0,
            "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
            "throttled_until_millis" : 0
          },
          "description" : "delete-by-query [test]",
          "start_time_in_millis" : 1605004115156,
          "running_time_in_nanos" : 22672616111,
          "cancellable" : true,
          "headers" : { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then after a few moments this task does not existed and it got terminated, sometimes it continues to run but sometimes it fails frequently, as I noticed my bulk retries number is high. What is an efficient way to delete my docs, approx  200 million docs to be deleted.

Comment: Can you add `&wait_for_completion=false` to your delete by query call and then you can run this call to get more information into what went wrong after the task has stopped running: `GET .tasks/_search`

Comment: the response that I shared above was after running this command, GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*/delete/byquery

Comment: Yes, but after the task has stopped running, you have no idea what went wrong because the task results have not been stored... Adding `&wait_for_completion=false` will give you that information

Comment: So what do you get when running `GET .tasks/_search` after the task has abruptly ended?